# Creating a function that accepts another function as a parameter

Tags: javascript

I am following along to an example of a custom forEach function in javascript. I just want to make sure that I understand what's going on...

```
   const myArray = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];

   Array.prototype.myLoop = function(func) {
     for(let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
       func(this[i]);  
     }
}

   myArray.myLoop( function(color) {
      console.log(color);
   });
```

So, I understand what the basic function is doing - My confusion lies in the execution of the code.

If, for example, I enter:

```
   myArray.myLoop(alert)
```

It would alert each colour - note how no parameter is given in this example.

However, when I use an anonymous function, I have to include the parameter:

```
myArray.myLoop( function(color) {
    console.log(color);
});
```

Now, from the first example, from what I think I understand - 'func' is a parameter, and inside the code, it says 'take whatever is passed as an argument and use the data from the array and output that' - (in this case, an alert)

In the second example - the anonymous function is passed - and inside the code it says:

```
func(this[i]);
```

So, in this example, the 'func' is passed the parameter 'this[i]' - which points to the current array item. So, basically, the function expects an argument, thats why you have to include 'color' in the anonymous function - 'color' is a placeholder name for the current array item.

I'm just kinda still confused on why you need an arguement for the annoymous function, but not the 'alert' - example:

```
myArray.myLoop(alert(color));
```

Could someone shed light on whats going on. What's the difference between the two example? Why a parameter for one, but not the other?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
myArray.myLoop(alert)
```

`alert` here is an existing, defined function, which you're passing as callback to `myLoop`.

```
myArray.myLoop(function (color) {
    console.log(color);
});
```

Here `function ...` is an anonymous function you're defining on the fly. It's equivalent to:

```
var f = function (color) {
    console.log(color);
};

myArray.myLoop(f);
```

At which point, as you can see, there's no difference to the way you pass `alert`. `f` is a function which accepts one parameter; `function (color) { ... }` is a function which accepts one parameter.

`f(a)` **calls** a function with an argument.
`function (p) { ... }` **defines** a function with a parameter (which you can later call).

Comment: So, just to clarify - the inner 'func' is the anonymous function that is being executed? 'func' expects an argument. That's why you have to include 'color'... inside that anonymous function, we console.log the 'this[i]' - so, the inner 'func' is a placeholder for the outer anonymous function...?

Comment: Functions are also "just values" that you can pass around. `myLoop(5)` passes the value `5`. `myLoop(alert)` passes the function `alert`. `myLoop(function (i) { ... })` also passes a function. You can assign functions to variables. Just as you can assign `5` to a variable or parameter, you can assign `function (i) { ... }` to a variable or parameter. The only difference between `5` and `function (i) { ... }` is that you happen to be able to *call* "function values", i.e. `func()`. Can't do that if `func` is `5`, but if `func` is `function () { ... }` you can.